# how to select real numbers by double clicking in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

because `.` is a word separator, a real number like `0.1` will be selected only `0` or `1`.

but if I remove `.` from word separators, the whole method call such as `a.b` or `a.b.c` will be selected, rather than `a`, `b` or `c` selected.

furthermore, `'` is also a possible separator between the digits, which can not be selected correctly as well.

so is there any extension that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the extension [Select By](https://github.com/rioj7/select-by) v0.10.0 you can select the text surrounding the current selection described with a regular expression.

If you add the following to your settings

```json
"selectby.regexes": {
  "selectFloat": {
    "surround": "[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?([eE][-+]?\\d+)?[fF]?"
  }
}
```

Place the cursor somewhere inside the number and execute the command `Select text range based on regex` and select the option `selectFloat` from the QuickPick list.

You can add a keybinding if needed

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+f",  // any key combo you like
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "command": "selectby.regex",
  "args": ["selectFloat"]
}
```

Comment: could I bind it on double clicking or some mouse operations? I think a key combo is a little Inflexible...

Comment: @RedFog learning to work with keyboard shortcuts speeds up the working with **any** application. AFAIK the double and triple click are hardwired in VSC

Answer (score -1):

This extension [Quick and Simple Text Selection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbankier.vscode-quick-select) allows for selecting of everything within single quotes, double quotes, backticks, etc., although it requires keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: but a number will not always within a pair of some signals. I want to select `0.1f` in `float a = 0.1f;` by double clicking. how does this extension work in this case?

Comment: If that’s the case you’ll have to go to your VSCode `editor.wordSeparators` settings and remove `.` from the list of separator characters.

Comment: I mentioned it that _but if I remove `.` from word separators, the whole method call such as `a.b` or `a.b.c` will be selected, rather than `a`, `b` or `c` selected._ it's also unacceptable.